# Relation between order of the group, its center, and its conjugacy class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am not sure how to relate the conjugacy class of a group to the order of the group and its centralizer.

Say I have a group $G$ of order $16$ and a center $Z(G)$ of size $2$. Would there be a conjugacy class of size $2$ as well?

The first theorem that comes into my mind is that a group of order $p^3$ is either abelian or its center has size $p$. But this is quite different from what I want to prove.

Can someone please give me some advices how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: The notation $Z(G)$ refers to the *center* of the *group itself* which is not the same thing as a *centralizer* of a *particular element*. Rather, the centralizer of an element $g$ is denoted $C_G(g)$ (although admittedly some sources might use $Z_G(g)$). Do you understand the difference between center and centralizer? | A group acts on itself by conjugation. The conjugacy classes are the orbits, and the centralizers are the stabilizers. So by the orbit stabilizer theorem, the conjugacy class of an element $g$ has size equal to the index $[G:C_G(g)]$ where $C_G(g)$ is the centralizer of $g$.

Comment: The only relation the center has to all of this is that $Z(G)\le C_G(g)$ for all $g$, so we can say any conjugacy class size $[G:C_G(g)]$ must be a divisor of $[G:Z(G)]$.

Comment: Shoot. My bad. I should be claiming a center of size 2.

Answer (score 1):

Of course!  Let $G$ act on itself by conjugation; that is, $g\cdot x=gxg^{-1}$.  Then $G$ divides itself into orbits; each orbit is a conjugacy class.  The center is the set of size-$1$ conjugacy classes; that is, the fixed points.

By the [orbit-stabilizer relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside%27s_lemma), each orbit has size dividing the order of $G$.  In this case, that there are (possibly) orbits of size $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, and $16$.  Let there be $n_1$-, $n_2$-, $n_4$-, $n_8$-, and $n_{16}$-many such orbits (respectively).  Then we know that $n_1=2$, and seek to show $n_2>0$.  Since $G$ is not one giant orbit, we must have $n_{16}=0$.  Counting elements, $$16=|G|=n_1+2n_2+4n_4+8n_8$$  Substituting in $n_1$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
2\cdot 7=14 &=2n_2+4n_4+8n_8\\
&=2(n_2+2n_4+4n_8).
\end{align}$$

Now divide by two and take the result mod $2$.  Then $$1\equiv n_2\pmod{2}$$  In particular, $n_2$ cannot be $0$, as desired.

Obviously, this argument can be generalized: if $G$ has order $p^n$ and a center of size $p^k$, then $G$ must have a conjugacy class of size $p^k$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class equation and the fact that, for every $x\in G\setminus Z(G)$, strictly $Z(G)<C_G(x)<G$. If $Z(G)$ has order $2$, then the noncentral elements have centralizers of order $4$ or $8$; if all of them had order $4$, then all the nontrivial conjugacy classes would have size $4$. But there's no way to "cover" $G\setminus Z(G)$, of size $14$, with conjugacy classes of size $4$, only. Therefore, there must be conjugacy classes of size $2$.